# Error in ctypes with a function and a structure pointer

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I am trying to use C++ function (in a dll) with python. To do this, i use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) library.

My C++ code is library to use a [webcam](http://www.theimagingsource.com/en_US/) which exports a set of C functions.

This the function that I want use:

```
/*! Release the grabber object. Must be called, if the calling application
    does no longer need the grabber.
    @param hGrabber The handle to grabber to be released.
    @sa IC_CreateGrabber
*/
void AC IC_ReleaseGrabber( HGRABBER *hGrabber ); ///< Releas an HGRABBER object.
```

It is the release memory function

this the HGRABBER structure:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*! This is the handle of an grabber object. Please use the HGRABBER type to access
    this object.
*/
typedef struct HGRABBER_t__ { int unused; } HGRABBER_t; ///<Internal structure of the grabber object handle.
#define HGRABBER HGRABBER_t* ///< Type of grabber object handle. Used for all functions.
```

My code is:

Necessary Structure HGRABBER (it is named HGRABBER_TYPE in my case)

```
class HGRABBER_T(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("unused", ctypes.c_int)] 

HGRABBER_TYPE = ctypes.POINTER(HGRABBER_T)
```

The call function:

```
self._dllref =  ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(DLL_PATH)
self._grabber_handle = self._dllref.IC_CreateGrabber() 
 ....
 ...
 ....
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(ctypes.pointer(HGRABBER_TYPE(self._grabber_handle)))
```

and finally, the error that i receive:

```
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(ctypes.byref(HGRABBER_TYPE(self._grabber_handle)))
TypeError: expected HGRABBER_T instead of int
```

I checked other related posts, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119814/passing-a-structure-pointer-to-a-function-in-ctypes) but it didn't help me..

I appreciate any help!

**UPDATE:**

I applied restype and argtypes in order to specify argument and return values (thanks!).

With the modifications, the code is:

```
self._dllref =  ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(DLL_PATH)
self._dllref.IC_CreateGrabber.restype = HGRABBER_TYPE        
self._grabber_handle = self._dllref.IC_CreateGrabber() 
...
..
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber.argtypes = [HGRABBER_TYPE]
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(self._grabber_handle)
```

I should have multiple mistakes, now my error is:

```
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(self._grabber_handle)
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x6E657137
```

I checked the argument for the function (HGRABBER *hGrabber), argtypes for the release function should be:

```
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(HGRABBER_TYPE)]
```

With this modification, i get another different error:

```
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(self._grabber_handle)
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x6B0F1FE0
```

I am searching these errors, it seems a bad conversion of the pointer which i don't understand, the structure seems very simple to cast and  i don't see what i miss..

**UPDATE 2**

I missed to add ctypes.byref when i call the function, it has to be:

```
 self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(ctypes.byref(self._grabber_handle))
```

**UPDATE 3**

Unfortunately, i am getting a random error related with pointer argument (`(ctypes.byref(self._grabber_handle))`), sometimes the release function accepts the object but sometimes give this error:

```
    _dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(ctypes.byref(_grabber_handle))
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x5A694F44
```

Comment: You don't need to define the `_fields_` for `HGRABBER_T` since it's just used to create the opaque pointer type.

Comment: Ok, I will test the code without this _fields_, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the return type of `IC_CreateGrabber` such that you don't need the recast when you call `IC_ReleaseGrabber`.

For example:

```
self._dllref =  ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(DLL_PATH)

# here set the return type
self._dllref.IC_CreateGrabber.restype = HGRABBER_TYPE

# here set the argtypes
self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(HGRABBER_TYPE)]

self._grabber_handle = self._dllref.IC_CreateGrabber() 

self._dllref.IC_ReleaseGrabber(ctypes.byref(self._grabber_handle))
```

By setting the `restype` and `argtypes` of the library functions, ctypes knows how to handle the values from the C side of things.

Comment: This answer is correct, but in my opinion, it is important to specify that this answer ONLY fix a part of my problem. I had two mistakes. I will edit my post to explain it

Comment: @carlos.baez Yes, this looks correct. I missed the `HGRABBER*` when I looked at the original question.

Comment: Sorry @ebarr, i thought it was working but, unfortunately, randomly it throws a pointer exception `exception: access violation reading 0x5A694F44`....